# Get Non Expiry S3 URL to store it to dynamodb flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

Guys, I am working on an application that requires to upload an image to s3 and keep the URL in the dynamodb database, however after the upload the geturl function which I have generates the URL for a certain time which has an expiry, how do I get a URL with no expiry

```
Future<String> getUrl() async {
try {
  print('In getUrl');
  String key = _uploadFileResult;

  try {
    GetUrlResult result = await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: key);
    print(result.url);
    return result.url;
  } on StorageException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('GetUrl Err: ' + e.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

All S3 pre-signed URLs have an expiration time. Pre-signed URLs exist to share private S3 objects for a limited time.

If that's a problem for you then one option is to make the object public, if appropriate, and simply store its URL of the form `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cat.png`.

Alternatively, write a small application that responds to a specific URL (e.g. `https://myapi.mydomain.com/images/cat.png` and have that app create a pre-signed URL for the related object and issue a 302 redirect to send the client to the temporary, pre-signed URL.